# Expecting Python assertRaises() to fail, but test always passes

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am attempting to get into the practice of TDD so I have been trying to start with Python's unittest module. I have written a test which I fully expect to fail, but it always passes! Below is the test code:

```
def test_file_not_found_exception(self):
    invalid_config = "Testing/invalidExperiment.xml"
    experiment_with_invalid_config = MyClass(invalid_config)
    self.assertRaises(OSError, experiment_with_invalid_config.run_experiment())
```

and my class definition is as follows:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, experiments, output_directory = ".")
        self._experiments = experiments
        self._output_directory = output_directory
    def run_experiment(self):
        try:
            x = 2 # dummy statement
        except OSError:
            print "Experiment file not found"
        except:
            print "Unexpected Error"
```

I figure that the try block should always execute correctly so I am at a loss as to why my unittest keep passing. I am very new to OOP in Python so I may be making a very obvious mistake... Also, if I catch the exception in the try-except block of the run_experiment() method, should the assertRaises() call ever work?

Comment: I think because you are catching exception in your code, your test doesn't receives OSError exception.

Comment: I removed the try-except block from the method body and it still always passes... suspicious.

Comment: I'm not sure how your test doesn't fail either? Normally you don't call the function you pass to `self.assertRaises`

Comment: @user3467349 - Could you suggest a reworking of the test code?

Comment: Did the test actually run?

Comment: Usually you with out i.e. `with self.assertRaises(Exception): func()` or  `self.assertRaises(Exception, func)`, I don't know why it doesn't fail when you pass it a value.

Comment: @Simeon Visser: Yes. Ran that test (my only one) and gave the OK status.

Comment: @user3467349 - How is my calling of the function any different from the second one you suggested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the function `MyClass.run_experiment` and passing it's output to self.assertRaises, for which reason it does not properly register an error when it fails to raise.

Incorrect Example:

```
import unittest
class MyClass(object): 
    def __init__(self, config): 
        pass
    def run_experiment(self): pass

class MainTest(unittest.TestCase): 
    def test_file_not_found_exception(self):
        invalid_config = "Testing/invalidExperiment.xml"
        experiment_with_invalid_config = MyClass(invalid_config)
        self.assertRaises(OSError, experiment_with_invalid_config.run_experiment())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Correct:

```
with self.assertRaises(OSError): 
    experiment_with_invalid_config.run_experiment()
```

Or

```
self.assertRaises(OSError, experiment_with_invalid_config.run_experiment)
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not notice that I was supposed to run it without the parenthesis. Also, in your rephrasing of my example you did not include the extraneous parenthesis, so what you marked as an incorrect example is actually correct!

Comment: I was surprised you weren't getting an error, because normally something like `1()` or `None()` would raise a `TypeError` but apparently if `None` is passed to self.assertRaises, it will not try to call `None()` as it would if a not None, non-callable value such as `1` passed. It's a peculiar behaviour.

Comment: Very strange indeed. Once again thanks for the help!